# Python list.remove() not working as expected. It is removing from multiple lists when I'm clearly specifying only one

Tags: python, list

If I am only removing words from the words_left list, why are they also being removed from the word_list and why is not removing 'maegan' which clearly does not have a 'b'.

```
word_list = ['susan', 'bill', 'terry', 'brian', 'black', 'ryan', 'maegan']
words_left = word_list

for word in word_list:
    if 'b' not in word:
        words_left.remove(word)
        
print(words_left)
print(word_list)
```

This returns:

```
['bill', 'brian', 'black', 'maegan']
['bill', 'brian', 'black', 'maegan']
```

Not, as I expected, this:

```
['bill', 'brian', 'black']
['susan', 'bill', 'terry', 'brian', 'black', 'ryan', 'maegan']
```

I'm clearly misunderstanding how the remove function works on lists or am missing something else that isn't entirely obvious to me.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you think `words_left = word_list` does?  (Hint: it *doesn't* make a copy of `word_list`.)

Comment: Read: https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html?highlight=list%20copy

Comment: As an aside, even if you had properly copied the list, using something like `words_left = word_list.copy()`, then your code would still be buggy, because you *should not `.remove` from a `list` while you iterate over it*. Every time you `.remove` from it, all the indices are shifted, so effectively, you'd *skip* the next iteration. That is why it isn't removing `'maegan'`, because when you removed `'ryan'` it skipped the next item.

Comment: So, for the main question, see the first duplicate target, for the second minor question, see the second duplicate target

Comment: thanks @Luuk. That's what I needed. .copy().